# How to include external Python code to use in other files?

Tags: python

If you have a collection of methods in a file, is there a way to include those files in another file, but call them without any prefix (i.e. file prefix)?

So if I have:

```
[Math.py]
def Calculate ( num )
```

How do I call it like this:

```
[Tool.py]
using Math.py

for i in range ( 5 ) :
    Calculate ( i )
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You will need to import the other file as a module like this:

```
import Math
```

If you don't want to prefix your `Calculate` function with the module name then do this:

```
from Math import Calculate
```

If you want to import all members of a module then do this:

```
from Math import *
```

**Edit:** [Here is a good chapter](https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/object_oriented_framework/importing_modules.html) from [Dive Into Python](https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/toc/index.html) that goes a bit more in depth on this topic.

Comment: Worth noting that `from Math import *` is [not recommended](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: You may interesting `imp` module and magic call `__import__`.

Comment: Someone forgot to renew their domain :\

Comment: This only works if `Math.py` and `Tool.py` are in the same directory.

Answer (score 56):

Just write the "include" command  :

```
import os

def include(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename): 
        execfile(filename)


include('myfile.py')
```

@Deleet :

@bfieck remark is correct, for python 2 and 3 compatibility, you need either :

Python 2 and 3: alternative 1

```
from past.builtins import execfile

execfile('myfile.py')
```

Python 2 and 3: alternative 2

```
exec(compile(open('myfile.py').read()))
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do this over `from module import *`? Also, if the file you're calling has code in the body, that code will be run, if you do this.

Comment: @naught101 : That's the goal : to run the code, which does not happen with an import. Ususally it's just defining variables.

Comment: This does not work for me.<ipython-input-2-eb60e21cee1f> in include(filename)
      1 def include(filename):
      2         if os.path.exists(filename):
----> 3                 exec(filename)
      4 

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Running ipython 3.4.

Comment: @Deleet python 3 doesn't have `execfile`

Comment: Actually python 3 has another signature for `compile()` than mentioned. So the correct Python 2 and 3: alternative 2 will be:
`exec(compile(source=open('myfile.py').read(), filename='myfile.py', mode='exec'))`

Comment: The 'include' helper function doesn't work if you want to have variables in the included file in scope in the caller of 'include'

Comment: It's incorrect to say that code is not run on import. It is. Try making a sample module yourself and see. Further, `exec` seems to me to be a security vulnerability waiting to happen, in the vein of running `subprocess` with `shell=True`.

Comment: `exec(compile(source=textwrap.dedent(open('myfile.py').read()), filename='myfile.py', mode='exec'))`  will work  if you want to have variables in the included file in scope in the caller of 'include', just insert it as normal python. If the python version support pathlib, use `exec(textwrap.dedent(pathlib.Path('myfile.py').read_text()))`. By the way, `exec(compile(open('myfile.py').read()))` does not run in my testrun (Python 3.6 Win10) .

Comment: @Louis an import of a Python module actually does execute the code. (Variable/function/class definitions are all executable statements in Python.)

Answer (score 34):

If you use:

```
import Math
```

then that will allow you to use Math's functions, but you must do Math.Calculate, so that is obviously what you don't want.

If you want to import a module's functions without having to prefix them, you must explicitly name them, like:

```
from Math import Calculate, Add, Subtract
```

Now, you can reference Calculate, Add, and Subtract just by their names. If you wanted to import ALL functions from Math, do:

```
from Math import *
```

However, you should be very careful when doing this with modules whose contents you are unsure of. **If you import two modules who contain definitions for the same function name, one function will overwrite the other, with you none the wiser.**

Answer (score 2):

It's easy and simple:
you can just do this:

```
def run_file(path):
    return exec(open(path).read());

run_file("myfile.py");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the python inspect module to be very useful

For example with teststuff.py

```
import inspect

def dostuff():
    return __name__

DOSTUFF_SOURCE = inspect.getsource(dostuff)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    dostuff()
```

And from the another script or the python console

```
import teststuff

exec(DOSTUFF_SOURCE)

dostuff()
```

And now **dostuff** should be in the local scope and **dostuff()** will return the console or scripts **_*name*_** whereas executing test.dostuff() will return the python modules name.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to emphasize an answer that was in the comments that is working well for me.  As mikey has said, this will work if you want to have variables in the included file in scope in the caller of 'include', just insert it as normal python.  It works like an include statement in PHP.  Works in Python 3.8.5.

Alternative #1

```
import textwrap 
from pathlib import Path
exec(textwrap.dedent(Path('myfile.py').read_text()))
```

Alternative #2

```
with open('myfile.py') as f: exec(f.read())
```

I prefer Alternative #2 and have been using it in my website development.