# "Sourcing" a Python file from another

Tags: python

I have a service where users upload egg files. The problem is that a `settings.py` file needs to be extracted by me and I should only accept some of the values in that file. The file consists of regular Python variables like:

```
VAR1 = 'Hello'
VAR2 = ['my.list']
VAR3 = {
    'a': 'b'
}
```

I need to extract these variables in a good manner and I have looked for a way to 'source' (Bash term I suppose..) the `settings.py` file to my worker Python file to extract the variables. I haven't found a way to do that when searching. Any ideas?

**My (specific) solution**

```
# Append path to sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname('/path/to/settings.py'))

import settings as egg_settings
LOGGER.info('Settings: VAR1 = %s', egg_settings.VAR1)

# Remove from sys.path
sys.path.pop(0)
```

Comment: Do you have some criteria for which variables you'd like to accept, and which to ignore?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714881/how-to-include-external-python-code-to-use-in-other-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just do `import settings` all the variables will be available like `settings.VAR1` `settings.VAR2` etc.

Comment: Thanks, this was obvious but I needed to hear it obviously :). I updated my question with a more detailed solution that worked fine for me. The springing point being that I needed to add a part of the egg to the `sys.path` and then remove it again.