# how to insert code in a python script on-the-fly?

Tags: python

I'm not sure what this is called but this is what I need. A portion of code in a python script that is stored in another file. When the script runs, automatically the code is inserted.... something like a function but without arguments passing.

```
line 100
line 101
line 102
line 103
line 104
```

I want lines 101-103 to be stored in another file. When the python script executes, lines 101-103 are automatically inserted as it is. So now my code looks like this

```
line 100
read code from another file
line 104
```

Even better, if I am able to select which codes to insert in between lines 100 and 104 (e.g. from file 1 or file 2 depending on condition)
I don't want to use a function because it involves a lot of variable passing.

Comment: not clear how you are trying this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714881/how-to-include-external-python-code-to-use-in-other-files

Comment: @Vivek - that question is not the same - note the OP's requirement to have access to local variables. However, one of the answers IS the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
if condition==1:
    execfile('filename1.py',globals(),locals())
else:
    execfile('filename2.py',globals(),locals())
```

**UPDATE:** To show that variables are accessible back and forth:

f1.py:

```
x='ha'
execfile('f2.py',globals(),locals())
print('after: '+x)
```

f2.py

```
print('before: '+x)
x='blah'
```

Output:

```
before: ha
after: blah
```

Therefore, the value of x is passed to f2.py and the value set there is then accessible in f1.py.

Comment: That seems to work, but with limitation- either the variables of the main file was not seen by the secondary file or the variables (or changes to them) in the secondary file was not seen by the main file. I tried this with various combinations of globals(),locals().

Comment: Works for me in py2.7. Suggest there is something else going on with your code that makes it seem as though it's not working. See update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `m4` for this.  Put this in `stuff.py`:

```
print 1
print 2
include(other.py)
print 3
print 4
```

And this in `other.py`:

```
print 'a'
print 'b'
```

And run it this way:

```
m4 stuff.py | python
```

The above assumes a *nix system (because those have `m4`).  If you have a system with a C compiler but no `m4`, you can use the C preprocessor instead!  Just change `include(other.py)` to `#include "other.py"` and run with `cpp` (or whatever the C preprocessor is called on your system) instead of `m4`.  This is rather more hacky, but perhaps more portable.

Comment: All well and good until you want to choose the include file based on a condition that is evaluated within the python script its self - ie in real time vs just before runtime.

Comment: @AdamKerz: well you can still `include()` within an `if` condition, but it will make indentation tricky.  :)  I like your answer if it works for the OP.

Comment: You are spot on @John Zwinck - I didn't think of that, but, as you say, there is the complication of the indentation issue :-)

Comment: @Sören: You'll need to be more specific if you want help.  Did you try it and get an error message?