# How to include text within a python file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

There are several questions related to reading python code from external files, including

[Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

[How to include external Python code to use in other files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714881/how-to-include-external-python-code-to-use-in-other-files)

But it's not clear how to include snippets of text from an external file, as is standard practice with the CPP `#include` directive.  For example, the following code:

```
def get_schema():
    schema1 = \
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "0",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "i": { "type": "integer" },
        "n": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
    return(schema1)

s = get_schema()
print(s)
```

returns the expected dict:

```
{'id': '0', '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'i': {'type': 'integer'}, 'n': {'type': 'string'}}}
```

But what I want to do is write the code so that it imports variable definitions from external files that do not include any python code (function definitions or variable assignments):

```
def get_schema():
    schema1 = \
#include "schema1.json"
    return(schema1)

s = get_schema()
print(s)
```

I'm sure this could be done with a bunch of code to open the definition files, read the contents into a string, add pre- and post-amble lines of python, and then exec the string, but it seems that there should be a simpler way to just include text in a function definition.  Is there?

Comment: Python has no preprocessor so you cannot include text that is later compiled as you can in C. There is no `#ifdef` for instance. Although you can skip executing a block with `if 0` the block is compiled into byte code and takes up space in the executing image.

Comment: Not sure what you are after exactly. It seems to me that you have a problem, thought of a possible solution (using a c/c++ paradigm) and want to implement that in python. Maybe if you explain you original problem better, we can provide a pythonic solution. Could you provide a more general example of the kind of things you would put in the external file? I see from your comment below that you are interested in something more general than loading JSON data.

Comment: For the general case "it can't be done" is a reasonable answer.  Separating the development and configuration management of json files from Python files seems like a good practice, and if that pattern ever comes up again for a different type of data (perhaps constant definitions?), knowing that the correct approach is to use or write an import routine is better than wondering if there is a built-in alternative.

Comment: @jorgeh, it struck me as remarkable that a subset of syntactically valid json strings are also syntactically valid Python rvalues.   Two questions follow from that:  1) are there any valid json strings that are not valid directly-executable Python, and 2) are there any other independently-developed data formats that are subelements of Python syntax.   But given that Python cannot import anything smaller than a module, no further thought needs to be given to those questions.

Comment: @Dave, there is a least a case where valid JSON is not valid python: `{"flag": true}`. JSON accepts lower-case `true`, but python will fail with that. There might be other cases, but at least this one answers your first question. I have no clue about your second question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load json from a file you can use [**`json`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) library:

```
import json

def get_schema():
    with open('schema1.json', 'r') as f:    
        return json.load(f)
```

Comment: You might want to change `'schema1'` to `'schema1.json'`. Otherwise, if this doesn't answer the question, clarification will be needed (imo).

Comment: i agree, but i don't know for sure if his file has json extension

Comment: Yes this answers my immediate use case of importing json.  But I'm still interested in the general question of whether it is possible to import units smaller than a complete module in python the way header files are imported into C programs.

Comment: i don't think it's possible in python @Dave