# how to use function defined in other python file?

Tags: function, python-3.5

Lets say we have two programs `A.py` and `B.py` ,now `B.py` has two defined functions

`calculator(x,y)` which returns `int`  and makelist(list1)`which returns`list`

Now,how can I access these functions in `A.py` (Python 3)?

Comment: I think this post is similar to the one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714881/how-to-include-external-python-code-to-use-in-other-files). I hope that helps

Comment: @aakashgupta.0205 i imported all functions using command  `from B import* ' now it is showing import error that no module named A ,even when i saved both the programs in same location i also changed A to A.py then also same error.

Comment: you're importing B into A, am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to import the other file, that is B, as a module

```
import B
```

However, this will require you to prefix your functions with the module name. If instead, you want to just import specific function(s) and use it as it is, you can

```
from B import *    # imports all functions from B

-or-

from B import calculator   # imports only the calculator function from B
```

> UPDATE

Python does not add the current directory to `sys.path`, but rather the directory that the script is in. So, you would be required to add your directory to either `sys.path` or `$PYTHONPATH`.