# How to combine python scripts

Tags: python

I found these codes from various websites: `ping.py` and `conf.py`. It's working fine. I need to combine these files into a single file.

`ping.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import smtplib
import pyping
from conf import settings, sites
import time
import datetime

"""Sends an e-mail to the specified recipient."""
sender = settings["monitor_email"]
recipient = settings["recipient_email"]
subject = settings["email_subject"]
headers = ["From: " + sender,
    "Subject: " + subject,
    "To: " + recipient,
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
session = smtplib.SMTP(settings["monitor_server"],
settings["monitor_server_port"])
session.ehlo()
session.login(settings["monitor_email"], settings["monitor_password"])
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

   for site in sites:
   checker = pyping.ping(site)
   # The site status changed from it's last value, so send an email

   if checker.ret_code == 0:

    # The site is UP
    body = "%s This Server is up %s" % (site, st)
    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
else:
    # The site is Down
    body = "%s This Server is down %s" % (site, st)
    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)

  session.quit()
```

`conf.py`:

```
sites = (
"192.168.1.1",
"192.168.2.1",
"192.168.3.1",
)

settings = {
"recipient_email": 'tomail@domain.com',
"monitor_email": 'frommail@domain.com',
"monitor_password": 'password',

# Leave as it is to use gmail as the server
"monitor_server": 'frommail@domain.com',
"monitor_server_port": 587,

# Optional Settings
"email_subject": 'Server Monitor Alert'
}
```

How to integrate `conf.py` into `ping.py` so I can get output from running a single file?

Comment: What do you mean with combin ? Cant you gust copy and paste the code?

Comment: This question already has an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604453

Comment: when i put   recipient = tomail@gmail.com its not working  , I want to pass values directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the **entire file** since `"recipient_email": 'tomail@domain.com'` is not valid variable definition.

Replace `from conf import settings, sites` with the file contents, or better, define the variables as you want them.

For example, rather than

```
sender = settings["monitor_email"]
recipient = settings["recipient_email"]
subject = settings["email_subject"]
```

Do

```
sender = "frommail@domain.com"
recipient = "tomail@domain.com"
subject = 'Server Monitor Alert'
# TODO: Define other values
```

> when i put recipient = tomail@gmail.com its not working

You need quotes around string variables...

Comment: These lines produce errors                                                                       session = smtplib.SMTP(settings["monitor_server"],                                               
session.login(settings["monitor_email"], settings["monitor_password"])

Comment: What about it? Again, use the other variable names, not those from `settings`. In fact, delete `settings` variable entirely.

Comment: As written, `TODO`... You must define the other values, or in-line them. `smtplib.SMTP('frommail@domain.com', ...`

Comment: And buddy this works fine in windows but when i run it on linux bash it gives me error                                                                        ./ping.py: line 1: $'\r': command not found
from: too many arguments
./ping.py: line 7: $'\r': command not found
./ping.py: line 8: settings: command not found
./ping.py: line 12: $'\r': command not found
./ping.py: line 14: monitor_server:: command not found
./ping.py: line 16: $'\r': command not found
./ping.py: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: I don't know why bash is interpreting your file directly. Do `python ping.py`

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the complete content of `conf.py` into `ping.py` just after the

```
import datetime
```

line. Then remove the line

```
from conf import settings, sites
```

from `ping.py`.

Note that doing so is usually quite the opposite of what you should be doing in terms of good coding style. Generally, you want to modularize your code, while this means taking (more or less) modular code and turning it into a big and unwieldy clump.